# When are modular forms linearly independent modulo $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, congruences

Let $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ be the space of weight $2$ modular forms for $\Gamma_0(N)$ and let $f_1, \dots, f_r$ be a basis of normalized eigenforms for $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$. Given a rational prime $p$, I'll say that the eigenforms $f_1, \dots, f_r$ are *linearly independent mod $p$* if the mod $p$ reductions of the Fourier expansions of $f_1, \dots, f_r$ are $\mathbf{F}_{p^k}$-linearly independent in $\mathbf{F}_{p^k} [[ q ]]$.

*My question is*: what are sufficient conditions on $N$ and $p$ that ensure that $f_1, \dots, f_r$ are linearly independent mod $p$? For example, if $N$ is prime and $p$ divides the numerator of $(N-1)/12$, then $f_1, \dots, f_r$ are *not* linearly independent mod $p$, because there is an Eisenstein series which is congruent to a cuspform in $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$. Are there sufficient conditions on $N$ and $p$ that ensure linear independence of the forms $f_1, \dots, f_r$?

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know about the "modular degree" condition you mentioned. In my case, I'm happy to assume that $N$ is prime. If $N$ is prime, then which primes $p$ do we have to exclude? Unfortunately, I don't think I can assume that one of the forms $f$ comes from an elliptic curve.

Comment: I'm looking for a sufficient condition like: "if $N$ is prime and $p$ does not divide the numerator of $(N-1)/12$, then the eigenforms of $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ are linearly independent mod $p$". Mazur showed that if $p$ divides the numerator of $(N-1)/12$, then this false, so I'm wondering if once we exclude this case, we have linear independence mod $p$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand the question. The normalized eigenforms need not have coefficients in ring of algebraic integers that contains a prime ideal with norm $p$. Do you mean to allow the reductions to have Fourier expansions in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k}}$? (For an explicit example, what about $N = 23$ and $p = 3$?)

Comment: @JeremyRouse Yes, exactly - I'm allowing reductions to have expansions in $\mathbf{F}_{p^k}$.

Comment: @user491858 I think you are not actually answering the question that is being asked; if there are three eigenforms $f, g, h$ in the space, and $f$ corresponds to an elliptic curve $E$ but $g, h$ do not, then the degree of the modular parametrisation of $E$ doesn't tell you anything about whether $g$ and $h$ satisfy a congruence.

Comment: @AdithyaChakravarthy The $\mathbb{Z}$-subalgebra of $End(M_2(\Gamma_0(N)))$ generated by the Hecke operators coprime to $N$ is a semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, so its discriminant is a non-zero integer, well-defined up to sign, and the primes where congruences occur are precisely the primes which divide this integer. See Calegari and Stein, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406243.pdf, for the prime-level case. But giving explicit bounds for the discriminant in terms of $N$ is probably very hard and messy.

Comment: Suppose $N$ is prime. Hecke Theory and the Sturm bound imply that if $f \ne g$ are eigenforms there exists a prime $v < N$ with $a_v(f) \ne a_v(g)$. (The actual Sturm bound is better.) $a_v(f)$ and $a_v(g)$ are algebraic integers of degree at most $N$ (an upper bound for $\mathrm{dim}(S_2)$) and they have absolute value $\le 2 \sqrt{v} < 2 \sqrt{N}$ for all real places. Thus their difference, which has degree $\le N^2$, has norm at most $(4 \sqrt{N})^{N^2}$. If $f$ and $g$ were congruent modulo $p$ this norm would be divisible by $p$. So there are no congruences if $p > (4 \sqrt{N})^{N^2}$.